# TemplateDoesNotExist : Template Not being detected on Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, templates, django-views, django-templates

Thanks to land at my concern.
I would be thankful if you will help me out.

Earlier i was doing same procedure to fetch the template, that time working. But recently i tried to make another project, now this time, getting "TemplateDoesNotExist" error.

```
technicalcourses/Courses.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.0.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
technicalcourses/Courses.html
Exception Location: C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\ravik\\Desktop\\Django_New_Project\\edureka',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Sun, 31 May 2020 19:54:29 +0000
```

Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

```
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\ravik\Desktop\Django_New_Project\edureka\template\technicalcourses\Courses.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\technicalcourses\Courses.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\technicalcourses\Courses.html (Source does not exist)
```

****Here Below I have completed- Kindly attached images ****

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add your code as a text.

Comment: It's templates directory not template. Maybe because of this you are getting error. And add your app_name to INSTALLED_APP in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

in your settings.py file you should have direction to your template path:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
    },
]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/